# How to make Emacs sql-mode recognize MySQL #-style comments?

Tags: sql, emacs, comments, elisp, sql-mode

I'm reading a bunch of MySQL files that use # (to end-of-line) comments, but my sql-mode doesn't support them.  I found the syntax-table part of sql.el that defines /**/ and -- comments, but according to [this](http://www.zvon.org/other/elisp/Output/SEC561.html), Emacs syntax tables support only 2 comment styles.

Is there a way to add support for # comments in sql.el easily?

Comment: Rather than lookup zvon.org, you can use the doc that comes with your Emacs: `C-h i m elisp RET m syntax flags RET`.  If you have a recentish Emacs it'll say: `A comment style is a set of flags ‘b’, ‘c’, and ‘n’, so there can be up to 8 different comment styles.`  But of course, in this particular case this is irrelevant, since `#...\n` and `--...\n` are considered as 1 style (since you can't have a comment starter (or ender) that belongs to two different styles).

Answer (score 4):

Emacs-24 sql.el has this built-in!  Simply run `M-x sql-set-product MySQL RET` and the syntax table is set up automatically, as are the font-lock-keywords for all the additional reserved words and types, interactive-mode, etc, etc.  Brilliant!!

Of if you look under `SQL` in the menubar you can use the `Product` submenu to select `MySQL`.

You can also `M-x customize-variable sql-product RET` to set the default product away from ANSI.

Answer (score 2):

The answer by Rolf did not seem to work for me. AFAIK, the character class for starting comments, of the alternative comment style should be "< b", not " b". This what I use:

```
    (add-hook 'sql-mode-hook 'my-sql-mode-hook) 
    (defun my-sql-mode-hook ()   
      ;; Make # start a new line comment in SQL. This is MySQL-specific
      ;; syntax.
      (modify-syntax-entry ?# "< b" sql-mode-syntax-table))
```

Comment: This solution did the trick for me. Thanks @arvixx!  v24.2.50.1

Comment: This worked for me, but then I discovered MySQL support is built-in to Emacs-24!!  See my answer for details.

Comment: The `set-syntax-table` in your function is redundant.

Answer (score 1):

You can define ?# to start comment-style b, which means there are two ways of starting the alternative comment style (either -- or #):

```
(setq sql-mode-syntax-table
  (let ((table (make-syntax-table)))
    ;; C-style comments /**/ (see elisp manual "Syntax Flags"))
    (modify-syntax-entry ?/ ". 14" table)
    (modify-syntax-entry ?* ". 23" table)
    ;; double-dash starts comments
    (modify-syntax-entry ?- ". 12b" table)
    (modify-syntax-entry ?# " b" table)
    (modify-syntax-entry ?\f "> b" table)
    ;; single quotes (') delimit strings
    (modify-syntax-entry ?' "\"" table)
    ;; double quotes (") don't delimit strings
    (modify-syntax-entry ?\" "." table)
    ;; backslash is no escape character
    (modify-syntax-entry ?\\ "." table)
    table))
```

(This was copied from sql.el and modified, which means that this is GPL)