# How to default emacs sql-mode comments to c-style?

Tags: sql, emacs

Does anyone know how to set Emacs to use `/* */` comments in SQL mode by default instead of `--`?

Clarification: I want to insert `/* */` when I type <kbd>M-;</kbd>, but by default it inserts `--`.  I am not concerned with font coloring or anything.

I usually write sqlite and postgresql code, if that matters, but it shouldn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like

```
(add-hook 'sql-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (setq comment-start "/* ")
            (setq comment-end " */")))
```

might do it, tho it's 100% untested.

Comment: Works great -- thanks.  I do wonder what happened to the hyphen comment syntax, though.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand what you mean by "what happened to the hyphen comment syntax".

Comment: Oh, just curious about whether '--' is stored anywhere for easy access or if it just gets overwritten.  No big deal, really, just curious.

Comment: No, I don't think it's stored anywhere for easy access.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know much about it, but I think you can edit the syntax table to change how emacs works. The answer on this thread explains it a lot better than I could, since I've never personally gotten to work with emacs. Aside from that, I unfortunately don't have anything for you. 
[How to make Emacs sql-mode recognize MySQL #-style comments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484826/how-to-make-emacs-sql-mode-recognize-mysql-style-comments)

Comment: The question isn't how to recognize the syntax coloring, which is what the other answer addresses.